# Resolve IPv6 address from hostname

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

We're updating our socket code to handle the new iOS requirements where you need to be able to connect in an IPv6-only environment.

We're currently using .NET sockets and TcpClient.

I'm trying to set up a solution where both IPv6 and IPv4 work, but so far nothing's happening.

If I use:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.BeginConnect( "server.hostname.com", 8182, this._onConnect, client );
```

in a IPv6 environment, I get no response; the `_onConnect` method will never get triggered.

If I use:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient( AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6 );
client.BeginConnect( "server.hostname.com", 8182,this._onConnect, client);
```

I get the `SocketException`:

```
An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used (errorCode: 10047, socketErrorCode: AddressFamilyNotSupported, nativeErrorCode: 10047)
```

Which is annoying, if understandable. If I use:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient( AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6 );
client.BeginConnect( "xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx", 8182,this._onConnect, client);
```

Then I can connect, however:

- I'm now putting in a raw IP address instead of a host name, which isn't good
- This will no longer work in an IPv4 environment

So I figured I could get the supported IPs from the hostname and try to connect to one after the other.

With this code:

```
IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry( "server.hostname.com" );
foreach(IPAddress ip in hostInfo.AddressList)
    Debug.Log( "Ip: " + ip.ToString() + ": address family: " + ip.AddressFamily );
```

It'll only print out the IPv4 IPs, which isn't super helpful.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get the IPv6 IP from a string hostname? Or is there a better way to resolve this?

I was kind of under the assumption that this would auto-resolve on the DNS level, but I guess the version of Mono included with Unity isn't up-to-date enough.

Thanks

Comment: It's the `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` class that comes with .Net (I think Unity is on .Net 2.0): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in mono, passing the **hostname** to create or connect to server will fail. Using the direct IP always work. Unity has not updated mono socket stuff for a long time. There is nothing wrong with using the IP.

The missed the Apple deadline which was on the 1st. My suggestion to you is to first check if your app is running on iOS then then use IPv6 for everything. If IPv6 fails or returns null then use IPv4.

> It'll only print out the IPv4 IPs, which isn't super helpful.
>
> What am I doing wrong here? How can I get the IPv6 IP from a string
>   hostname? Or is there a better way to resolve this?

It's printing out the **IPv4** because you did **not** filter it. You have to manually check if the ip is a an IPv6 in each loop.

```
//IPv4
if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
{
}

//IPv6
if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
{
}
```

If **IPv6** is not found even after using the solution above to filter it out then that means that the network you are on does **not** support **IPv6**. When I say that, I mean your ISP. If your ISP did not give you an **IPv6** then you can't connect to another public server with **IPv6**. You will only connect to public servers with the **IPv4** your ISP assigned to you.

To very this, visit [here](http://ipv6-test.com/) and [here](http://test-ipv6.com/). It will tell you if you have **IPv4**, **IPv6** or both.

The code below is a general function I use to retrieve local, public IP including version 4 and 6.

```
private string getIPAddress(string hostName, IPTYPE ipType, ADDRESSFAM Addfam)
    {
        //Return null if ADDRESSFAM is Ipv6 but Os does not support it
        if (Addfam == ADDRESSFAM.IPv6 && !System.Net.Sockets.Socket.OSSupportsIPv6)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //////////////HANDLE LOCAL IP(IPv4 and IPv6)//////////////
        if (ipType == IPTYPE.LOCAL_IP)
        {

            System.Net.IPHostEntry host;
            string localIP = "";
            host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (System.Net.IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                //IPv4
                if (Addfam == ADDRESSFAM.IPv4)
                {
                    if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        localIP = ip.ToString();
                    }
                }

                 //IPv6
                else if (Addfam == ADDRESSFAM.IPv6)
                {
                    if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
                    {
                        localIP = ip.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            return localIP;

        }

        //////////////HANDLE PUBLIC IP(IPv4 and IPv6)//////////////
        if (ipType == IPTYPE.PUBLIC_IP)
        {
            //Return if hostName String is null
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostName))
            {
                return null;
            }

            System.Net.IPHostEntry host;
            string localIP = "";
            host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
            foreach (System.Net.IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                //IPv4
                if (Addfam == ADDRESSFAM.IPv4)
                {
                    if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        localIP = ip.ToString();
                    }
                }

                //IPv6
                else if (Addfam == ADDRESSFAM.IPv6)
                {
                    if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
                    {
                        localIP = ip.ToString();
                    }
                }

            }
            return localIP;
        }
        return null;
    }


    enum IPTYPE
    {
        LOCAL_IP, PUBLIC_IP
    }

    enum ADDRESSFAM
    {
        IPv4, IPv6
    }
```

Usage:

```
    Debug.Log("Local IPv4: " + getIPAddress("", IPTYPE.LOCAL_IP, ADDRESSFAM.IPv4));
    Debug.Log("Local IPv6: " + getIPAddress("", IPTYPE.LOCAL_IP, ADDRESSFAM.IPv6));

    Debug.Log("Public IPv4: " + getIPAddress("google.com", IPTYPE.PUBLIC_IP, ADDRESSFAM.IPv4));
    Debug.Log("Public IPv6: " + getIPAddress("google.com", IPTYPE.PUBLIC_IP, ADDRESSFAM.IPv6));
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I nailed down the problem as it seems the iOS code is different in the backend. I've accepted the answer as it answers the question, but long story short, the host name *will* work in iOS, but throws an exception in the editor and android. I've opened a bug with unity on it

Comment: Also `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.OSSupportsIPv6` throws an exception on Android - it might be related. `SupportsIPv6` seems to work, but it marked as obsolete

Comment: @divillysausages Yes, it is a bug and I stopped relying on using hostname directly. I wouldn't use a code that works in one Os but not in another. Anyways, remove the `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SupportsIPv6` from the get IP function if it throws an exception. Kudo's for opening a bug. Make sure to to post your bug here too http://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/05/10/unity-and-ipv6-support/. Unity will take the network bug seriously at this moment if you post it there because Apple made that a requirement and Unity is making sure that no one's App gets rejected or thrown out because of their mistake.

Answer (score 3):

@Programmer's code gives the IP address for a hostname, but I wanted to clarify 2 things.

1) The code:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient( AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6 );
client.BeginConnect( "server.hostname.com", 8182,this._onConnect, client);
```

*DOES* work, but only on iOS. In the editor and on Android, it gives an exception (as of Unity 5.3.5f1). This seems like a bug in the implementation, so I've sent in a bug report.

2) Despite `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SupportsIPv6` being marked as obsolete and Unity advising you to go with `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.OSSupportsIPv6`, `OSSupportsIPv6` will throw an exception on Android

Comment: After delving deeper into it, it turns out the problem was in ".Net 2.0" and ".Net 2.0 Subset" compatibility level. The Subset worked, while the full didn't. Changing to the subset, I can now use a hostname and `Socket.OSSupportsIPv6` no longer throws an exception - bug report: https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?804510_c5ei44diq6ktnh1u